# Java Spring ошибка при redirect

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Web приложение на Spring Web. Обработчик, по мимо всего прочего, формирует pdf документ, и передаёт на скачивание. Всё без исключения  работает, но не срабатывает return "redirect:/search"; Если удаляю код с формированием документа, то редирект срабатывает и никаких ошибок.

```
@PostMapping("/removes")
public String removes (@RequestParam Long id,
                       @RequestParam String invid,
                       MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse remform, Map<String, Object> model) throws IOException{

                    Message messagedel = new Message(id);

                    Streamable<Message> messag;
                    messag = messageRepo.findByInvid(invid);

                    final String FONT = "fonts/segoeuisl.ttf";
                    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                    Font font = new Font(bf, 12, Font.NORMAL);

                    remform.setContentType("application/pdf");
                    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
                    String headerValue = "attachment; filename=destroy.pdf";
                    remform.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

                    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
                    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, remform.getOutputStream());

                    document.open();
                    document.add(new Paragraph("Акт", font));

                    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
                    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
                    Stream.of("Наименование", "Инв. №", "Инициатор")
                            .forEach(columnTitle -> {
                                PdfPCell head = new PdfPCell();
                                head.setPadding(5);
                                head.setHorizontalAlignment(1);
                                head.setPhrase(new Phrase(columnTitle, font));
                                table.addCell(head);
                            });
                    for (Message mess : messag) {
                        table.addCell(mess.getText());
                        table.addCell(mess.getInvid());
                        table.addCell(GetDn.displayName);
                    }
                    document.add(table);
                    document.close();

                    messageRepo.deleteById(id);
                    journalFind.deleteByMessageid(id);
                    model.put("messages", messagedel);
                    return "redirect:/search";
}
```

Ошибка:

```
ERROR 19644 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed

ERROR 19644 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.e.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView : Cannot render error page for request [/removes] and exception [] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, `response` у вас закрывается PDFWriter-ом. Засим вы и не можете больше модифицировать оный.

Выход, согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35556282/3212712) - указать редирект до использования PDFWriter так:

```
remform.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
remform.setHeader("Location", targetURL);
```

Comment: Увы, но при использовании его в любом месте кода приводит к 
ошибкам в других действиях. 

`org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer] with root cause
com.lowagie.text.ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer`

Например, не удаляются строки из БД.
Если использовать после document.close(), то та же ошибка выходит и нет редиректа(